Is the phrase "amorphous blob" redundant
The phrase "amorphous blob" has some common usage and is seen is popular stories such as I have no mouth, but I must scream
Is the phrase redundant as the word blob already implies amorphous?

If you actually provide a specific usage we could give better guidance, but you should remember that the goal of language isn't to express things in the fewest words possible. Amorphous is a nice word rich in connotation and interesting sounds. That's why it's used in fiction, where a fortiori the goal isn't to write the fewest words or else every story would just be "they married" or "they died".

A blob may resemble no particular named shape; but that blob's shape may be permanent, like dried paint. Amorphous has the connotation that the shape is changeable - like a putty, gel, or liquid.

Amorphous may genuinely man having no shape, but blob does not really mean that at all (words don't automatically or straightforwardly mean what dictionaries say they do!). A blob has some kind of roundness to it. Truly amorphous things don't, necessarily. So an amorphous blob is a kind of roundish shapeless thing, where shapeless means you couldn't quite give its shape a name. If you doubt this, try thinking of a randomly mega-spiky 3D thing. Can't be a blob. Because blobs have round edges, not spikes.

If you doubt Araucaria WRT blobs having round edges, and spikes having sharp, see phonosemantics on ELU (where you will see some delightful posts from the late Prof. Lawler, and Sound Symbolism on Wikip.

Yes, it's redundant, but entirely acceptable.  Over the years, the phrase has carried texture and meaning.  What @StuartF said makes my comment redundant, but I wanted emphasize how well he responded!

Amorphous:

adjective
having no definite form: SHAPELESS

MW
Blob:

noun
something shapeless

MW
Yes, but if you need a noun, blob can also mean:

: a small drop or lump of something viscid or thick
: a daub or spot of color

MW
I suspect that context would normally push people toward this being fully redundant, but common usage may need more disambiguation. To say you are blobbing around, or laying around like a blob doesn't really emphasize the shape you're in. In my mind, it's more around emphasis than something entirely redundant, like a red-headed red head.

I'd normally imagine a blob as near-circular, but amorphous suggests a much wigglier or oddly-shaped outline. Maybe that's just me, though.

Another way to parse "amorphous blob" is to read amorphous as meaning something other than "shapeless." MW offers two definitions of amorphous that might modify blob in distinct, nonrepetitive ways: "being without definite character or nature: unclassifiable" and "lacking organization or unity." So "an amorphous blob" may signify not "a shapeless thing that is shapeless" but "a shapeless thing that is unclassifiable or unidentifiable" or "a shapeless thing that is utterly disorganized." In either case, the modifier amorphous doesn't simply reiterate the "shapeless" quality of the blob.
